# Change Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have a table in Oracle which has following schema:

```
City_ID  Name  State  Country  BuildTime  Time
```

When I declared the table my primary key was both `City_ID` and the `BuildTime`, but now I want to change the primary key to three columns:

```
City_ID  BuildTime  Time
```

How can I change the primary key?

Comment: See also [Drop Primary Key](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/primary_keys.php#:~:text=The%20syntax%20to%20drop%20a,of%20the%20table%20to%20modify)

Answer (score 85):

Assuming that your table name is `city` and your existing Primary Key is `pk_city`, you should be able to do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE city
DROP CONSTRAINT pk_city;

ALTER TABLE city
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_city PRIMARY KEY (city_id, buildtime, time);
```

Make sure that there are no records where `time` is `NULL`, otherwise you won't be able to re-create the constraint.

Comment: How will it affect the indexes created on the primary key?

Answer (score 46):

You will need to drop and re-create the primary key like this:

```
alter table my_table drop constraint my_pk;
alter table my_table add constraint my_pk primary key (city_id, buildtime, time);
```

However, if there are other tables with foreign keys that reference this primary key, then you will need to drop those first, do the above, and then re-create the foreign keys with the new column list.

An alternative syntax to drop the existing primary key (e.g. if you don't know the constraint name):

```
alter table my_table drop primary key;
```

Comment: my primary key is a combination of city_id and buildtime
so what should write in place of my_pk

Comment: I was using "my_pk" as the name of the primary key constraint.  You should know what the name of the constraint is, but if you don't you can use "alter table my_table drop primary key;" instead.

Comment: One does not need to drop dependent foreign keys that reference my_table.my_pk if one drops it using the CASCADE clause.  Also, just dropping the constraint may keep an index around you may or may not want; use the KEEP | DROP INDEX clause to as appropriate.

Oddly enough, all of this is documented in the Oracle Database SQL Reference.  

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2103845

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes when we do these steps:

```
 alter table my_table drop constraint my_pk; 
 alter table my_table add constraint my_pk primary key (city_id, buildtime, time);
```

The last statement fails with

> ORA-00955 "name is already used by an existing object"

Oracle usually creates an unique index with the same name my_pk. In such a case you can drop the unique index or rename it based on whether the constraint is still relevant.

You can combine the dropping of primary key constraint and unique index into a single sql statement:

```
alter table my_table drop constraint my_pk drop index;
```

check this:
[ORA-00955 "name is already used by an existing object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993456/ora-00955-name-is-already-used-by-an-existing-object)