# Adding primary key to existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, composite-primary-key

Can i add a new column to a table which already has a primary key such that the new column and existing primary key form a composite primary key ?

Comment: Yes, please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310561/change-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly - you'll have to drop the existing primary key and create a new one. Note that primary key columns must not be `null`. E.g.:

```
-- Add the new column
-- Make sure it doesn't have any nulls in it
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD newcolumn NUMBER(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;

-- Drop the primary key
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY;

-- Add a new primary key
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pk 
PRIMARY KEY (oldcolumn1, oldcolumn2, newcolumn);
```

Comment: Thanks it cleared my doubt