# Change PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT in PostgreSql using Play Framework Evolutions

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, primary-key, alter-table

I need to change a `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` in PostgreSql **from a single to a composite key**, using Scala's [Play Framework Evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Evolutions). This [Change Primary Key post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310561/change-primary-key) gives me a good head start, so I will adapt their example; suppose my db evolutions `1.sql` file is:

```sql
-- !Ups
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id int,
    "version" int
);

CREATE INDEX city__version ON city("version");
CREATE INDEX city__group_id ON city(group_id);

-- !Downs
DROP TABLE city;
```

I want to change the `PK` to include 2 more columns, like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id BIGSERIAL,
    group_id int,
    "version" int,
    CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY (city_id, group_id, "version");
);

-- ...
```

I think the `2.sql` file should look like:

```sql
-- !Ups
ALTER TABLE city 
  DROP COLUMN city_id, 
  ADD COLUMN city_id BIGSERIAL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY (city_id, group_id, "version");

-- !Downs
ALTER TABLE city 
  DROP CONSTRAINT city_pk,
  DROP COLUMN city_id,
  ADD COLUMN city_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

But I wonder if I need to truncate the table first*, since I'm dropping an essential column... If so, should I include a `TRUNCATE` command to the evolution file before the `ALTER TABLE` command? Otherwise, is there another way to change the `PRIMARY KEY` w/o `DROP` + `ADD COLUMN`?

* it's OK to do it on my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested my suggested changes and it worked. The `2.sql` file is the same as suggested; there was no need to truncate the table first, and the original data was preserved, including the `city_id`:

```sql
-- !Ups
ALTER TABLE city 
  DROP COLUMN city_id, 
  ADD COLUMN city_id BIGSERIAL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT city_pk PRIMARY KEY (city_id, group_id, "version");

-- !Downs
ALTER TABLE city 
  DROP CONSTRAINT city_pk,
  DROP COLUMN city_id,
  ADD COLUMN city_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```